# how can i know if the target weight is match for the weeks that have a data?

Tags: r

```
target weight         week.3        week.4         week.5
7.4                     5.0           6.9            7.5
```

how can I match or determine in what week they the target weight match maybe greater than or equal to the target weight? what code can I use?

Comment: Chai Decena, welcome to SO! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your data is in a data.frame as it should be. Then you can do it like this.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(target=7.4, week3=5.0, week4=6.9, week5=7.5)
df <- df %>% 
  gather(key=week, value=weight, starts_with("week")) %>% 
  mutate(achieved = weight > target) %>% 
  print()
#>   target  week weight achieved
#> 1    7.4 week3    5.0    FALSE
#> 2    7.4 week4    6.9    FALSE
#> 3    7.4 week5    7.5     TRUE
df$week[df$achieved]
#> [1] "week5"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Simon Woodward, your code is correct but I need a condition that the answer is the week like instead of TRUE or FALSE the answer gonna be week, instead of FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, the answer is - , - , week5

Comment: And "week5" is what I gave you.

Comment: it looks likes this https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqwj8izzmh14znh/screenshot%202019-07-19%2015.48.54.png?dl=0

Comment: they gave me TRUE , FALSE https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jcgd9mhxoc1uz2/screenshot%202019-07-19%2015.48.42.png?dl=0

Comment: I want to look like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfcgr1stmbpm9u9/screenshot%202019-07-19%2016.10.59.png?dl=0